# Extracting a series of integers using a loop

Tags: r, loops, multiple-columns

I have some data where I want to extract the frequency with which the integers appear. Here is some sample data:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="A B C D 
1          1         5          3         1  
2          1         2          3         2  
3          2         3          5         3  
4          1         4          5         3  
5          3         1          4         2  
6          5         2          5         1 
") 
df
```

I can loop through these and get the counts as follows:

```
for (i in 1:5){ 
 print(colSums(df==i))
}
```

But every time I try to store the output I get an error. What is the neatest way to store the resultant output in a dataframe? I think I'm getting confused about the way to store data that's run through a loop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your desired output based on this input? A for-loop is not the way to go most of the time. How were you storing the output?

Comment: @Heroka THe desired output is already showed by the OP

Comment: For each column header I want to be able to clearly see how many times there were 1s, 2s, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(df))
#  A B C D
#1 3 1 0 2
#2 1 2 0 2
#3 1 1 2 2
#4 0 1 1 0
#5 1 1 3 0
```

---

In `base R`,  we can also `unlist` the dataset, replicate the column names, and use `table` (not using any loop, explicit (`for`) or implicit (`lapply`).

```
table(unlist(df),names(df)[col(df)])
#   A B C D
# 1 3 1 0 2
# 2 1 2 0 2
# 3 1 1 2 2
# 4 0 1 1 0
# 5 1 1 3 0
```

Or as @nicola mentioned, the instead of `col(df)`, we can use `rep` (should be faster)

```
table(unlist(df), rep(names(df),each=nrow(df)))
```

Comment: Great solutions. In the `base` one I'd prefer `rep(names(df),each=nrow(df))` (instead of `names(df)[col(df)]`), but I know you like `row` and `col` a lot :)

Comment: @nicola Thanks for your feedback.  I think the `rep` should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike @akrun, I prefer to use base R when possible.

```
out <- matrix(0, nrow= 6, ncol=4, dimnames= list(1:6, LETTERS[1:4]))
for (i in 1:6) {
  out[i,] <- unlist(lapply(df, function(j) sum(j == i)))
}

R> out
  A B C D
1 3 1 0 2
2 1 2 0 2
3 1 1 2 2
4 0 1 1 0
5 1 1 3 0
6 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: So I think your answer addresses my confusion. I need to use a separate index in j, I think I was using i as an index twice in my attempts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I agree on the base-R. However, in this case, why not use `table` instead of a for-loop?

Comment: @Heroka It's my personal preference to use language agnostic tools when possible. It's a similar philosophy to that of using base R... Yes, I recognize that this isn't a purely language agnostic solution (`lapply`, `unlist`) but those are just data structure constructs

Comment: Just to note, I get the error `Error in out[i, ] <- unlist(lapply(df, function(j) sum(j == i))) :   object 'out' not found`, if I copy and paste @Alex 's response

Comment: Just about anything is possible in base R. But using packages often makes things easier

Comment: I think it was a copy-paste mistake, I added the matrix assignment to `out`.

Answer (score 1):

We could also do this in base-R without a for-loop:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(df, function(x){table(factor(x,levels=1:6))}))

  A B C D
1 3 1 0 2
2 1 2 0 2
3 1 1 2 2
4 0 1 1 0
5 1 1 3 0
6 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: +1 but, well, lapply is a wrapper for a loop, as you know. So I'm not sure I'd call this a solution without a loop. But you said correctly without a `for` loop ;-)

Comment: I know. But to me, `lapply(df, ...` is a lot more elegant than `for(i in 1:ncol(df))`. The joys of R, 100 ways to the same outcome :)

Comment: I agree. lapply is nicer.

Comment: I think levels should be 1:5 (the 6 is the row number in the post)

Comment: You're right. However, it was `1:6` in an earlier version of the question, so I assumed that were the possible occuring numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
library(reshape2)
table(melt(df))
#No id variables; using all as measure variables
#        value
#variable 1 2 3 4 5
#       A 3 1 1 0 1
#       B 1 2 1 1 1
#       C 0 0 2 1 3
#       D 2 2 2 0 0
```